# Formula for expectation of Bivariate Data

Tags: expectation, uniform-distribution, bivariate-distributions

`Suppose that $(X, Y )$ has a uniform distribution on the parallelogram with vertices at

- $(0,0)$
- $(1292,1000)$
- $(1526,0)$
- $(2818,1000)$

Calculate the means of $X$ and of $Y$.

I don't know the formula for expectations of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Let $\Omega$ be the parallelogram.  You have to calculate
\begin{align}
\Bbb{E}[X] &= \frac{\iint_\Omega x dxdy}{\underbrace{\iint_\Omega dxdy}_{\mbox{Area of $\Omega$}}} \\
\Bbb{E}[Y] &= \frac{\iint_\Omega y dxdy}{\underbrace{\iint_\Omega dxdy}_{\mbox{Area of $\Omega$}}}
\end{align}
Can you set up the integrals and show us your work?

Comment: I worked it out and got 1409 as the mean of $X$ and 500 for the mean of $Y$.

Comment: So does $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's a well-known formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of this particular question, the means of $X$ and $Y$ will be just the geometric center of the parallelogram as it is a uniform distribution.

*Intuitive understanding*

Think of the parallelogram as a dartboard, with one corner at the origin and its length on the X-axis. Think of the uniform distribution as a uniform force attracting darts, all across the parallelogram. Just consider the X-axis. When you throw darts at this parallelogram, since the force is uniform across X-axis, the mean of the darts will be the mean of length along the X-axis. A similar logic shows that the mean along Y-axis will be the mean of the height.